# How can I get the count of user likes on a fan page 

Tags: facebook

I want to get the total count of user likes on a fan page via graph api or FQL, the count should be of any like whether the user liked the comment, post or any other activity  on that fan page e.g I liked 10 activities(comment, other user post) on some fan page now what i want is the count of my likes on that page via graph api or fql, which will be 10.

Thanks in advance or helps are definitely appreciated

Comment: What is your question? Do you have some code to show?

Answer (score 0):

Reference : [Facebook dev docs Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/)

Using graph API
http://graph.facebook.com/19292868552
will give you the number of likes for a page with ID `19292868552`

**FQL:**

`likes` is the column in `Page` table which contains the number of likes for a Page

Comment: Dhiraj, I think you miss understood the question, I am having a problem to get the count of specific user likes not the over all like count of a fan page, well thx for your instant reply

Comment: Agreed I misunderstood. Question was: 'count of user's like on a page'. It will either be 1 or 0, he likes or does not like. So what are you interested in knowing ?

Comment: ok here it goes e.g I liked 10 activities(comment, other user post) on some fan page now what i want is the count of my likes which will be 10

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy,
Just put your facebook id i.e. 
specific id of a page or album or photo in FQL(Facebook Query Language)
in URL: https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20like_info%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20object_id=10151134287325803